# Is it safe to call [EAGLContext presentRenderBuffer:] on a secondary thread?

Tags: ios, multithreading, opengl-es

I have (multiple) `UIViews` with layers of type `CAEAGLLayer`, and am able to call [`EAGLContext presentRenderBuffer`:] on renderbuffers attached to these layers, on a secondary thread, without any kind of graphical glitches.

I would have expected to see at least some tearing, since other UI with which these `UIViews` are composited is updated on the main thread.
Does `CAEAGLLayer` (I have `kEAGLDrawablePropertyRetainedBacking` set to `NO`) do some double-buffering behind the scenes?

I just want to understand why it is that this works...

Example:

`BView` is a `UIView` subclass that owns a framebuffer with renderbuffer storage assigned to its OpenGLES layer, in a shared `EAGLContext`:

```
@implementation BView

-(id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame context:(EAGLContext*)context
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    // Configure layer
    CAEAGLLayer* eaglLayer = (CAEAGLLayer*)self.layer;
    eaglLayer.opaque = YES;
    eaglLayer.drawableProperties = @{ kEAGLDrawablePropertyRetainedBacking : [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], kEAGLDrawablePropertyColorFormat : kEAGLColorFormatSRGBA8 };

    // Create framebuffer with renderbuffer attached to layer    
    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];
    glGenFramebuffers( 1, &FrameBuffer );
    glBindFramebuffer( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, FrameBuffer );    
    glGenRenderbuffers( 1, &RenderBuffer );
    glBindRenderbuffer( GL_RENDERBUFFER, RenderBuffer );
    [context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER fromDrawable:(id<EAGLDrawable>)self.layer];    
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, RenderBuffer );

    return self;
}

+(Class) layerClass
{
    return [CAEAGLLayer class];
}`
```

A `UIViewController` adds a `BView` instance on the main thread at init time:

```
BView* view = [[BView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect){ 0.0, 0.0, 75.0, 75.0 } context:Context];
[self.view addSubView:view];
```

On a secondary thread, render to the framebuffer in the `BView` and present it; in this case it's in a callback from a video AVCaptureDevice, called regularly:

```
-(void) captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput*)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection*)connection
{    
    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:bPipe->Context.GlContext];

    // Render into framebuffer ...

    // Present renderbuffer
    glBindRenderbuffer( GL_RENDERBUFFER, BViewsRenderBuffer );
    [Context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];
}
```

Comment: post your code snippet

Comment: Who is updating the contents of the buffer? The main thread or your secondary thread?

Comment: @JoaEbert updates and presentation, as shown in the code I just added, are done on the secondary thread

Answer (score 0):

It used to not work. There used to be several issues with updating the view if the buffer was presented on any but the main thread. It seems this has been working for some time now but it is on your own risk to implement it as you do. Later versions may have issues with it as well as some older probably still do (not that you need to support some old OS versions anyway).

Apple was always a bit closed as to how things work internally but we may guess quite a few things. Since iOS seems to be the only platform that uses your main buffer as a FBO (frame buffer object) I would expect the main frame buffer is inaccessible for development and your main FBO is actually redrawn to the main frame buffer when you present the render buffer. The last time I checked the method to present the render buffer will block your current thread and seems to be limited to the screen refresh rate (60FPS in most cases) which implies there is still some locking mechanism. Some additional test should be done but I would expect there is some sort of a pool of buffers which need to be redrawn to the main buffer where in the pool only one unique buffer id can be present at the time or the calling thread is blocked. This would result in the first call to the present render buffer would not be blocked at all but each sequential would be if the previous buffer has not yet been redrawn.

If this is true then yes, a double buffering is mandatory at some point since you may immediately continue drawing to your buffer. Since the render buffer has the same id over the frames it may not be swapped (for what I know) but it could be redrawn/copied to another buffer (most likely a texture) which can be done on the fly at any given time. In this procedure then when you first present the buffer you will copy the buffer to the texture which will be locked. When the screen refreshes the texture will be collected and unlocked. So if this texture is locked your presentation call will block the thread, otherwise it will continue smoothly. It is hard to say this is double buffering then. It has 2 buffers but it still works with a locking mechanism.

I do hope you may then understand why it works. It is pretty much the same procedure you would use when loading large data structures on the separate shared context which runs on a separate thread.

Still most of this is just guessing unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, this is pretty much how I see it. I remember in the past that presenting on a secondary thread would cause problems. And now suddenly it works. I decided to see what would happen, since the docs don't explicitly prohibit this afaik, and it just worked. I posted on the Apple dev forums but no-one answered. Would be good to know exactly what is going on here. Not because the app is broken, just to know whether this is legit and optimal. My guess, as you have suggested, is that `presentRenderbuffer` will automatically sync with the main thread presentations

Comment: I still wouldn't dare calling it on a non-main thread but this is your choice. I guess if at some point you start to find some anomalies all you would need to do is call the main thread to perform the presentation with the correct context and render buffer then simply continue the thread execution when the operation is finished. So in general there will be little extra time cost taking this risk.

Comment: Indeed. However the actual rendering would need to be synced too, which would in most cases hamper performance (especially UI). The rendering could instead be done into a secondary buffer, and then only the blit operation between this buffer and the view's layer renderbuffer need be synced. The presentation and the rendering are of course then thread-safe. This is what _I guess_ Apple does...

Comment: The rendering would be synced because your thread would wait for the main thread to be done with the presentation. This should be (almost) instant unless you are over the FPS limit in which case you should pause the rendering anyway (no sense in drawing more frequently then presenting).

Comment: I am not too sure the blit operation may be done when drawing to screen though. Since the render buffer size that is presented does not need to have the same size as the target (view pixel width) some interpolation must be done which implies to a normal texture redraw. By default you will get the buffer that has a rounded size of the UIView.frame which is 1x for all devices. I assume the texture is simply drawn as full screen (full frame actually) and is stretched if needed using linear interpolation.

Comment: Note that most (or even all) other implementations use a totally different system which is using a main frame buffer. This buffer does automatically resize with the view/window while the Apple buffer does not. I still expect there is a main buffer somewhere in the back but as far as I know it is not accessible. Still its index should be 0 so it might just be on a separate context and then your "main context" is in fact just a shared context.

Comment: Sorry by "blit" I was conceptually referring to a render with a basic texture look up shader, of course copying directly would make no sense